# Adding typescript file to PTVS project

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, ptvs

Typescript seems to be great alternative to javascript.
we are using paython for visual studio aka PTVS.

the problem there is no wat to add .ts file to the project

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general problem with VS projects, in that they themselves decide the "suitable" item types for Add New Item dialog. However, you can always add, say, a .txt file, and then rename it to .ts.